# Digital adjustment of the gain of the cut-off points of the analog filter

Tags: filter, gain, digital-filter, analog-filter

As seen in the graph, I have a bandpass filter.

[image]

The problem is that the signal gain decreases at the cutoff points, but I want my gain to create sharp corners, including the cutoff frequencies, and I want the gain to remain at 1.

[image]

I can achieve this by increasing the orders of the filters, but there are phase distortions and increasing the stages means more opamps and more cost. For this, I plan to use an ADC at the end of the filter. Then, I hope to multiply the frequencies where attenuation occurs by certain gain coefficients and make the gain equal to 1. Is there a special name given to this type of equalization in signal processing, or what are other more logical solutions?

Comment: The gain can't remain at exactly 1, so you need to determine what deviation from 1 is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, even at the middle points of the graph, there will be a slight slope in the gain and the gain will change with very small differences. However, there is a significant attenuation at the cutoff points and I want to overcome this.

Comment: Right. But we need to know your tolerances to know what you need here.

Comment: That's unrealistically tight.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem which is soon going to to cause a Z problem that sounds like "how to do 1 billion point FFT in real time." What 's the actual goal?

Comment: You will never achieve that kind of accuracy with analog circuitry due to the tolerance and drift of resistors and capacitors.  Your best bet is to use a low pass filter to limit the bandwidth, sample the signal and do digital filtering.